# stunnel - how to setup stunnel to handle ssl and attach http with it?

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl, certificates, tunneling

I am running Google App Engine which is a http web server with some redirecting and other real-time stuff. But it does not have SSL to include so its unable to make HTTPS.

Therefore, i was trying `stunnel` to make SSL and connect the HTTP on it, but its not working when using Google App Engine and Stunnel.

```
$ cat /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
pid = /stunnel.pid
cert=/var/tmp/server.pem
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
client=yes
; Some debugging stuff useful for troubleshooting
debug = 7
output = /var/log/stunnel.log
[SSL]
accept=0.0.0.0:443
connect=80
```

**See the logs:**

```
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG5[8293:140556325660608]: Threading:PTHREAD SSL:ENGINE Sockets:POLL,IPv6 Auth:LIBWRAP
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG6[8293:140556325660608]: file ulimit = 1024 (can be changed with 'ulimit -n')
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG6[8293:140556325660608]: poll() used - no FD_SETSIZE limit for file descriptors
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG5[8293:140556325660608]: 500 clients allowed
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8293:140556325660608]: FD 9 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8293:140556325660608]: FD 10 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8293:140556325660608]: FD 11 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8293:140556325660608]: SO_REUSEADDR option set on accept socket
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8293:140556325660608]: SSL bound to 0.0.0.0:443
2014.02.06 09:13:34 LOG7[8299:140556325660608]: Created pid file /stunnel.pid

2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325660608]: SSL accepted FD=12 from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49651
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325660608]: SSL accepted FD=13 from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49652
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL started
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: FD 12 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL started
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: TCP_NODELAY option set on local socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 13 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: Waiting for a libwrap process
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on local socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Waiting for a libwrap process
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: Acquired libwrap process #0
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Acquired libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: Releasing libwrap process #0
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Releasing libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: Released libwrap process #0
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Released libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL permitted by libwrap from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49651
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL permitted by libwrap from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49652
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325656320]: SSL accepted connection from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49651
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL accepted connection from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49652
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: FD 15 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 16 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG6[8299:140556325656320]: connect_blocking: connecting 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG6[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connecting 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: connect_blocking: s_poll_wait 82.x.x.x:80: waiting 10 seconds
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325656320]: connect_blocking: connected 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: s_poll_wait 82.x.x.x:80: waiting 10 seconds
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325656320]: SSL connected remote server from 82.x.x.x:36426
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connected 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: Remote FD=15 initialized
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL connected remote server from 82.x.x.x:36427
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: TCP_NODELAY option set on remote socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Remote FD=16 initialized
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on remote socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client hello A
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL alert (write): fatal: handshake failure
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG3[8299:140556325656320]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325656320]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client hello A
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325656320]: SSL finished (1 left)
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL alert (write): fatal: handshake failure
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG3[8299:140556325586688]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL finished (0 left)
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325660608]: SSL accepted FD=12 from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49653
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL started
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 12 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on local socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Waiting for a libwrap process
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Acquired libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Releasing libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Released libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL permitted by libwrap from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49653
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL accepted connection from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49653
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 13 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG6[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connecting 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: s_poll_wait 82.x.x.x:80: waiting 10 seconds
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connected 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL connected remote server from 82.x.x.x:36428
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Remote FD=13 initialized
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on remote socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client hello A
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL alert (write): fatal: handshake failure
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG3[8299:140556325586688]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL finished (0 left)
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325660608]: SSL accepted FD=12 from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49654
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL started
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 12 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on local socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Waiting for a libwrap process
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Acquired libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Releasing libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Released libwrap process #1
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL permitted by libwrap from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49654
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL accepted connection from 82.x.x.LocalPC:49654
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: FD 13 in non-blocking mode
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG6[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connecting 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: s_poll_wait 82.x.x.x:80: waiting 10 seconds
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: connect_blocking: connected 82.x.x.x:80
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: SSL connected remote server from 82.x.x.x:36429
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: Remote FD=13 initialized
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: TCP_NODELAY option set on remote socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): before/connect initialization
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL state (connect): SSLv3 write client hello A
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL alert (write): fatal: handshake failure
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG3[8299:140556325586688]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG5[8299:140556325586688]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
2014.02.06 09:14:06 LOG7[8299:140556325586688]: SSL finished (0 left)
```

EDIT: here to verify locally the ssL

```
$ openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1391675538
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

EDIT:

Goal: visitor visits a valid address for example: https://www.yumyumyum.com
(assume its valid and has CA, KEY, CERT files) and he is not forwarded to http://www.yumyumyum.com it should remain as https

1) when used Google App Engine it does not have HTTPS option as a result everything has to run as HTTP, now the service is running as HTTP, but when users use it as http, it causes other security problems

2) therefore, we needed a SSL Proxy to that HTTP so that the user always get https even behind the screen they are attached with http

is this clear description?

Comment: Would you please describe the complete data flow? I am not sure any more whether I have understood that correctly (which is important for the answer, of course).

Comment: Please see my last EDIT section

Comment: OK, that's what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your (default changing) setting

```
client=yes
```

But you need stunnel in server mode, i.e. an SSL/TLS connection is offered to the outside and forwarded as an unencrypted connection.

Comment: client=no i set like your suggestion. But now when i go to https://haukelaging.com it works but then instantly i get into http://haukelaging.com rather then https

Comment: @YumYumYum haukelaging.com? You connect to a domain that doesn't even exist...? See my comment to your question.

Comment: After changing to your suggestion its working. But for example `https://www.yumyumyum.com` i visit assume its a valid https certificate and domain. then i am automatically going to tihs `http://www.yumyumyum.com` instead of HTTPS it becomes HTTP.

Comment: Can you have a look at the HTTP headers? Maybe there is a redirection which does not even have anything to do with the SSL stuff.

Comment: YES - i did a test `1) iamServer1> echo 'server1 talking' | nc -l 80;  2) iamServer2> curl -v "https://iamServer1"  3) iamServer2>  gets http://iamServer1 instead of https://iamServer1`

Comment: But when i use in Step 1. Google App Engine then it does not work. could it be a reply 302 with http? causing that then?